# Which framework/lib can help me with rapid development Proxy server on java?

Tags: java, proxy, jetty, netty

I am looking any frameworks or libs which can help me with development easy and small proxy server for internal project needs.

I found Jetty and Netty. What other?

Also, I see, that Jetty is provides an Web server and javax.servlet container and
Netty is an asynchronous event-driven network application framework 
for rapid development of maintainable high performance protocol servers & clients.

So, I am not sure that Jetty is correct choose in my case.
Netty - I do not see any good documentation and community, possible, it is not a good choose too.

What can you recommend for me?

Comment: Are you looking for a proxy server that uses Java? Or are you going to develop your own proxy server? Netty is a framework but Jetty is a servlet container, not a framework.

Comment: @Ronixus, my own proxy server.

Answer (score 1):

I am sure either would work fine, speaking for Jetty we have an asynchronous ProxyServlet that you can configure and use directly, or override and customize as needed with any additional logic you have.  I know of a number of folks using it successfully in production in both ways.  I would recommend using the latest Jetty 9.0.2 release. The documentation is a bit sparse on it but we are working to add more as we continue migrating documentation over to docbook.

http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/proxy-servlet.html

If you have questions about things the documentation ought to be covering feel free to contribute to it (its on github) or open an issue at bugs.eclipse.org under RT/Jetty and we'll work to address it.

Comment: Depends on what he wants to proxy, something web-ish (http/1.0, http/1.1, https, spdy, websockets, http/2.0), or something else?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend [LittleProxy](https://github.com/adamfisk/LittleProxy). It's a highly customizable proxy server based on Netty.

Answer (score 1):

Actually Netty contains a simple TCP proxy server in its examples. So maybe its a good starting point for you. You can find it here [1].

[1] https://github.com/netty/netty/tree/4.1/example/src/main/java/io/netty/example/proxy

Answer (score 0):

Assuming HTTP context, you can also use Undertow. But couldn't find any example or documentation regarding HTTP Client except below.

[Proxy handler example](https://github.com/undertow-io/undertow/blob/1.3.x/core/src/main/java/io/undertow/server/handlers/proxy/ProxyHandler.java)

Edit:
[Here](https://github.com/undertow-io/undertow/tree/master/examples/src/main/java/io/undertow/examples/reverseproxy) you can find few easy to understand examples

Answer (score 0):

You can use vert.x it comes with easy to configurable HTTP Server.

```
HttpServer server = vertx.createHttpServer();

server.requestHandler(request -> {

  // This handler gets called for each request that arrives on the server
  HttpServerResponse response = request.response();
  response.putHeader("content-type", "text/plain");

  // Write to the response and end it
  response.end("Hello World!");
});

server.listen(8080);`
```

Answer (score 0):

You can consider `Zuul`. It is actively managed and used by `Netflix` and is open source
 [Netflix zuul](https://github.com/Netflix/zuul/blob/2.1/README.md)

Infact it is more than a proxy server.
`Zuul` GitHub says

Zuul is an edge service that provides dynamic routing, monitoring, resiliency, security, and more.